# How to copy an array of objects with unqiue address for every object

Tags: python, numpy

If I copy an array of 5 objects at the same address with copy.deepcopy(), they will all get a new address, but still not unqiue. I need all of the objects to be unique (at different addresses).

```py
import numpy as np
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


p = Person("John", 10)
a = np.array([p, p, p, p, p])
new_arr = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

**Before:**

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716a60>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716a60>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716a60>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716a60>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716a60>]
```

**After:**

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716520>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716520>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716520>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716520>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7fa608716520>]
```

This works (but is very slow) - I'm looking for the fastest solution. Imagine that the array has 1000000+ objects.

```
new_arr = []
for x in arr:
    new_arr.append(copy.copy(x))
```

**How it should be**

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x7f40f6fdc5e0>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7f40f7099100>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7f40f7099e20>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7f40f7099130>
 <__main__.Person object at 0x7f40f7090940>]
```

Comment: Can you instantiate five separate `Person` objects from the beginning?  `np.array([Person("John", 10), Person("John", 10), Person("John", 10), Person("John", 10), Person("John", 10)])`

Comment: This is a "feature" of deepcopy.  If the same object multiple times within the thing it is copying, it will make sure that in the deepcopy, they are still the same object, just a different same object.   See the documentation.  Classes can define their own __deepcopy__ implementation, but I don't think that will help here. as the checking for duplication happens before __deepcopy__ is called.  (Not sure, though.)

Comment: Sounds like you want a list comprehension instead of a for-loop; but you might have to live with creating millions of objects taking a little time.

Comment: The first code example uses a numpy array, the second a list. Which one are you dealing with, is it relevant to the issue?

Comment: An object dtype array is just a bastardized list,  You created one object, and put multiple references in the list/array.  You really should call `Person(...)` multiple times to make distinct objects.  Depending on `copy/deepcopy` to make new instances sounds convoluted and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to implement `copy()` so that `deepcopy()` works on your custom object.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __copy__(self):
        return Person(self.name, self.age)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return Person(deepcopy(self.name, memo), deepcopy(self.age, memo))
```

Comment: Running this code still gives the same object five times.  The memoization happens before __deepcopy__ is called.

Comment: Arrg.  My trying to type a python variable that starts and ends with double underscore is giving me bold instead.  Sorry.

Comment: @FrankYellin Put backticks around it. `\`__deepcopy__\``

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood says, use a list comprehension, but I don't know about the speed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import copy
>>> Class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

        
>>> p = Person('John', 42)
>>> p
<__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C55E06BB0>

>>> a = np.array([copy.deepcopy(p) for i in range(5)])
>>> a
array([<__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C64768580>,
       <__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C64768610>,
       <__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C64768670>,
       <__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C64768730>,
       <__main__.Person object at 0x0000017C64768790>], dtype=object)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "speed" when working with objects in a list or object dtype array (at least not in the sense of numeric numpy operations).